# Running a regression loop within a pipe + filtering by date

Tags: r

I want to loop a regression within a pipe, but don´t think I am structuring the pipe correct. Ive looked up previous questions here on stackoverflow, but neither seems to cover my needs. To be honest I am quite desperate as Ive spent A LOT of time on this and need to continue the analysis. You would therefore save my week if you manage to help me out here.

Needs:

1. group by company
2. regress for every date
3. using the interval [-20,-10] prior to that date.

For example: 2021-01-30 | TSLA --> regress the return on index factor for TSLA from 2021-01-10 to 2021-01-20 to calculate the beta and intercept for 2021-01-30. And do this for all dates for all companies

Attempt:

```
library(dplyr)

stocks %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  for i in seq_along(stocks$date){ 
    lm(Return~indexfactor, filter(stocks$date %in% ((i-20):(i-10)))
    }
```

Data:

```
stocks <-   structure(list(Company = c("TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", 
    "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", 
    "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", 
    "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", 
    "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "TSLA", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", 
    "AAPL", "AAPL", "AAPL", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
    "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
    "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
    "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", 
    "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT"), Return = structure(c(NA, 
    -0.00231580860313196, 0.00161115249502686, 0.0263778178160983, 
    0.00126177020327534, 0.00131321050919397, -0.0246270372908958, 
    0.00914064109251655, 0.00200537012113067, 0.0152319401903576, 
    0.00153470089029306, 0.00330255357802023, -0.0386048629818018, 
    0.0126135313891698, 0.016987201324169, 0.00226083596494164, 0.0275330390995761, 
    0.0219139834854407, -0.017438317910401, 0.00482277896193928, 
    -0.00746184998902322, -0.000335287830383391, 0.00813970000264619, 
    -0.00120277144206837, 0.00276710299297744, 0.0138741424465028, 
    -0.0102317198037775, 0.00821145028213532, 0.0174002689158261, 
    0.00665249242034749, 0.00892635726223312, 0.0301960379663551, 
    0.0321221724831346, -0.00671175495130083, 0.0017702430543638, 
    0.0325710468824816, NA, 0.00747491336551409, 0.004230452491915, 
    0.0154892997636558, -0.0100836108228525, -0.00670488036422623, 
    -0.0331018742668066, 0.0038934147553642, -0.00956207269350584, 
    0.00614369450930652, -0.00161045428175832, -0.0183479745173454, 
    -0.0213610573923191, 0.00342794874173857, 0.0168724333689398, 
    0.00671920438590856, 0.00061292650530631, -0.0105499797243396, 
    -0.0238012734333519, 0.00648296789562508, -0.00931178310842573, 
    0.00812716607773845, -0.0246056442175525, 0.0141584160856578, 
    0.00630712914529696, 0.00908445774647904, -0.00272174624225163, 
    -0.000629783091523284, -0.00910302512573391, -0.00423991959013226, 
    0.0202256115186827, 0.00751252808543867, 0.0118061795583038, 
    0.0150801225162718, 0.00336111869323474, 0.00147394484369379, 
    NA, -0.00225290073646667, -3.31363114687289e-05, -0.00318795893000134, 
    9.9933375639738e-05, -0.00985973514785521, -0.0051808544995795, 
    0.00432856189833641, 0.00942799115889392, 0.0167784043797137, 
    0.0013122301384898, -0.0175283598141395, -0.0185747393633032, 
    0.00169894672234916, 0.012822249504298, 0.00328223940876526, 
    -0.000701001473501162, -0.0173041352803581, -0.0362036357526352, 
    0.00169304112099122, -0.00732389788732402, 0.0254681919300281, 
    -0.0207195464395805, 0.0199569965714916, 0.0150643262548715, 
    0.00593640984287869, 0, -0.00210274711678327, -0.00458826751020991, 
    0.0117112569702396, 0.0217340016991259, 0.00482243104872015, 
    0.0101246444598198, 0.00305900606094878, -0.00266037365193483, 
    0.0108975178309423), .Dim = c(108L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
        "Delt.1.arithmetic")), date = structure(c(18871, 18872, 18873, 
    18877, 18878, 18879, 18880, 18883, 18884, 18885, 18886, 18887, 
    18890, 18891, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18897, 18898, 18899, 18900, 
    18901, 18904, 18905, 18906, 18907, 18908, 18911, 18912, 18913, 
    18914, 18915, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921, 18871, 18872, 18873, 
    18877, 18878, 18879, 18880, 18883, 18884, 18885, 18886, 18887, 
    18890, 18891, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18897, 18898, 18899, 18900, 
    18901, 18904, 18905, 18906, 18907, 18908, 18911, 18912, 18913, 
    18914, 18915, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921, 18871, 18872, 18873, 
    18877, 18878, 18879, 18880, 18883, 18884, 18885, 18886, 18887, 
    18890, 18891, 18892, 18893, 18894, 18897, 18898, 18899, 18900, 
    18901, 18904, 18905, 18906, 18907, 18908, 18911, 18912, 18913, 
    18914, 18915, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921), class = "Date"), indexfactor = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c("2021-09-01", 
    "2021-09-02", "2021-09-03", "2021-09-07", "2021-09-08", "2021-09-09", 
    "2021-09-10", "2021-09-13", "2021-09-14", "2021-09-15", "2021-09-16", 
    "2021-09-17", "2021-09-20", "2021-09-21", "2021-09-22", "2021-09-23", 
    "2021-09-24", "2021-09-27", "2021-09-28", "2021-09-29", "2021-09-30", 
    "2021-10-01", "2021-10-04", "2021-10-05", "2021-10-06", "2021-10-07", 
    "2021-10-08", "2021-10-11", "2021-10-12", "2021-10-13", "2021-10-14", 
    "2021-10-15", "2021-10-18", "2021-10-19", "2021-10-20", "2021-10-21", 
    "2021-09-011", "2021-09-021", "2021-09-031", "2021-09-071", "2021-09-081", 
    "2021-09-091", "2021-09-101", "2021-09-131", "2021-09-141", "2021-09-151", 
    "2021-09-161", "2021-09-171", "2021-09-201", "2021-09-211", "2021-09-221", 
    "2021-09-231", "2021-09-241", "2021-09-271", "2021-09-281", "2021-09-291", 
    "2021-09-301", "2021-10-011", "2021-10-041", "2021-10-051", "2021-10-061", 
    "2021-10-071", "2021-10-081", "2021-10-111", "2021-10-121", "2021-10-131", 
    "2021-10-141", "2021-10-151", "2021-10-181", "2021-10-191", "2021-10-201", 
    "2021-10-211", "2021-09-012", "2021-09-022", "2021-09-032", "2021-09-072", 
    "2021-09-082", "2021-09-092", "2021-09-102", "2021-09-132", "2021-09-142", 
    "2021-09-152", "2021-09-162", "2021-09-172", "2021-09-202", "2021-09-212", 
    "2021-09-222", "2021-09-232", "2021-09-242", "2021-09-272", "2021-09-282", 
    "2021-09-292", "2021-09-302", "2021-10-012", "2021-10-042", "2021-10-052", 
    "2021-10-062", "2021-10-072", "2021-10-082", "2021-10-112", "2021-10-122", 
    "2021-10-132", "2021-10-142", "2021-10-152", "2021-10-182", "2021-10-192", 
    "2021-10-202", "2021-10-212"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You want to apply `lm` for each date in each `Company` ? The data to be considered is between -10 and -20 of current date?

Comment: @RonakShah yes, I dont know how to describe it easily, but the main point is that I cant blend returns and indexfactors from different companies when calculating intercept and betas. 
For example:
2021-01-30  |   TSLA

--> regress the return on index factor for TSLA from 2021-01-10 to 2021-01-20 to calculate the beta and intercept for 2021-01-30. And do this for all dates for all companies

Comment: @RonakShah I will certainly buy you a coffee if you can help me out here:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

stocks %>%
  mutate(Return = c(Return)) %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  mutate(model = map(date, ~{
    tmp <- filter(cur_data(), between(date, .x-20, .x-10))
    if(nrow(tmp)) lm(Return~indexfactor, tmp)
    else NA})) %>%
  ungroup

#  A tibble: 108 x 5
#   Company   Return date       indexfactor model    
#   <chr>      <dbl> <date>           <int> <list>   
# 1 TSLA    NA       2021-09-01           1 <lgl [1]>
# 2 TSLA    -0.00232 2021-09-02           2 <lgl [1]>
# 3 TSLA     0.00161 2021-09-03           3 <lgl [1]>
# 4 TSLA     0.0264  2021-09-07           1 <lgl [1]>
# 5 TSLA     0.00126 2021-09-08           2 <lgl [1]>
# 6 TSLA     0.00131 2021-09-09           3 <lgl [1]>
# 7 TSLA    -0.0246  2021-09-10           1 <lgl [1]>
# 8 TSLA     0.00914 2021-09-13           2 <lm>     
# 9 TSLA     0.00201 2021-09-14           3 <lm>     
#10 TSLA     0.0152  2021-09-15           1 <lm>     
# … with 98 more rows
```

If there are no rows in data in the interval [-20,-10] prior to that date we return `NA`.

Comment: I try running the code, but get the following error:

> `library(dplyr)
> library(purrr)
> stocks %>%
+   mutate(Return = c(Return)) %>%
+   group_by(Company) %>%
+   mutate(model = map(date, ~{
+     tmp <- filter(cur_data(), between(date, .x-20, .x-10))
+     if(nrow(tmp)) lm(Return~indexfactor, tmp)
+     else NA})) %>%
+   ungroup
Error: `cur_data()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.`

Comment: I don't get any such error on the data shared. Probably that might be because you have `plyr` loaded. Try using `dplyr::mutate` to call the function explicitly from `dplyr`.

Comment: You were absolutely right. Im so happy right now.  Also, if I want to store the intercept and coefficient in two different columns, how do i do this? I tried assign your formula to a new df, but I get all output in a single cell.

Comment: You can make use of `broom::tidy` i.e Add the following to the above answer `%>% filter(!is.na(model)) %>%mutate(data = map(model, broom::tidy)) %>% unnest(data)`

Comment: hmm I try running the following code, but I get som strange results

`m <- stocks %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Return = c(Return)) %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  mutate(model = map(date, ~{
    tmp <- filter(cur_data(), between(date, .x-20, .x-10))
    if(nrow(tmp)) lm(Return~indexfactor, tmp)
    else NA})) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(!is.na(model)) %>%
  mutate(data = map(model, broom::tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(data)`